# To Japan - is the preposition necessary?

Tags: responses

In the following dialogue, is the preposition necessary, assuming "where" is equal to a preposition plus a noun denoting a place.

> A: Where did he go last week?

> B: **To** Japan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't necessary. Saying "Japan" would be equally acceptable.

Comment: Are you a native?

Comment: Spoken English natively for 40 years, yes, and I have a degree in English Language. You? :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to a question can be a fragment of almost any length, as long as it contains the necessary information, forms a contiguous piece of a grammatical sentence, and doesn't repeat part of the question.

In particular, some question words, including "where", imply a preposition, making the preposition optional, but allowed, in the answer. Both of your sentences are correct.

Comment: Is this okay? A: Where is John.   B: The living room.

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, that's okay.